# Parameter 'daterange' not found in the collection

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a problem calling my stored procedure in my database

this is my stored procedure in my database

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `sample`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_ReturnAttendanceInfo`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`192.168.%` PROCEDURE `sp_ReturnAttendanceInfo`(IN uname INT(4), IN daterange DATETIME)
BEGIN
        SELECT shift_time.in, shift_time.out, MIN(perf_prog.start_time) AS start_time, MAX(perf_prog.end_time) AS end_time, perf_prog.date FROM perf_prog INNER JOIN Shifts ON perf_prog.emp_id = Shifts.emp_id 
INNER JOIN shift_time ON Shifts.id = shift_time.id

WHERE perf_prog.emp_id = uname  AND  DATE(`date`) >= daterange

GROUP BY  `date` ORDER BY `date` ;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

when i call this stored procedure in database query
like this

```
CALL sp_ReturnAttendanceInfo(0921, '2017-04-02')
```

it returns an output

but when i call it in my c#

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConnection))
{
    connection.Open();
    if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_ReturnAttendanceInfo", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i even checked the parametre im passing:

```
921
2017-04-04
```

but still i can't solve it. i even search the problem before creating a question, but i can't solve it. the error message is still the same

and this is the error:

```
Parameter 'daterange' not found in the collection.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.GetParameterFlexible(String parameterName, Boolean throwOnNotFound)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetAndFixParameter(String spName, MySqlSchemaRow param, Boolean realAsFloat, MySqlParameter returnParameter)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both the parameters you pass into the stored proc and the parameters that accept those values have to be the same, thus change:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daterange", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```